# Update custom field in Salesforce internally and externally

Tags: community

In Salesforce, in Account component, I have a custom field called 'Timestamp'. This field is used for synchronization purposes with an external application. I need to achieve below scenarios with this field.

1. The field can be updated via Salesforce API. Here the field is updated with the external timestamp value (Now the 'Timestamp' value is different from 'Last Modified Time' in Salesforce).
2. If any Account related information is updated from Salesforce itself, then the field is updated with current time (Ideally equivalent to 'Last Modified Time' in Salesforce).

I tried Salesforce workflow rules for this but it only achieves the second scenario. For the first scenario it again updates the value with current time instead of the externally received value.

How to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: First scenario - the external app has to call an API and send the external timestamp value. There are out of the box APIs for this. Take a look at [APIs](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/api_basics) trailhead

Answer (score 0):

I believe the missing element here is a Custom Permission you can use to selectively deactivate your automation.

You'd create a Custom Permission, say `DontUpdateTimestamp`. Assign that Custom Permission via a Permission Set to your integration user(s). Then, in your automation (whether declarative or programmatic) check for this custom permission before you perform a field update. You can certainly do this in PB/Flow or in Apex; I can't recall offhand if it works in a Workflow Rule.

---

Another option would be to use Apex for some or all of the automation and build the trigger involved to be deactivatable when you need it to be. This offers maximal control if for some reason the Custom Permission approach isn't flexible enough.

The preferred way to do this is to have the trigger call some handler class, which has a static variable you can set to inhibit its operation while you make a change that you *don't* want to result in the Timestamp value changing. For example:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update) {
    AccountTriggerHandler.beforeUpdate(Trigger.new);
}

public class AccountTriggerHandler {
     public static Boolean shouldInhibitTimestamp = false;
     public static void beforeUpdate(List<Account> newList) {
        if (AccountTriggerHandler.shouldInhibitTimestamp) return;
        
        for (Account a: newList) {
            a.Timestamp__c = DateTime.now();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, a custom Apex REST service class can use the Boolean to inhibit trigger operation while it sets the desired value:

```
AccountTriggerHandler.shouldInhibitTimestamp = true;
myAccount.Timestamp__c = desiredValue;
update myAccount;
AccountTriggerHandler.shouldInhibitTimestamp = false;
```

The downside is that you have to use a custom REST API class instead of the native REST API.